# Delete sublist from a list

Tags: python, list

I want to delete a sublist from a list. I only know the starting index and the ending index. how can I delete from the list?

I'm using the following code:

```
def delete_sub_list( self, cmd_list, start, end ):
        tmp_lst = []
        for i in range( len( cmd_list ) ):
            if( i < start or i > end ):
                tmp_lst.append( cmd_list[ i ] )

        return tmp_lst
```

and I'm calling in the following way:

```
cmd_list = self.delete_sub_list( cmd_list, 4, 14 )
```

Comment: note: for interval comparison, you can directly write `start <= i <= end` to make it a little easier to read. In your case thought, you should use something else :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python syntax to do this is

```
del cmd_list[4:14 + 1]
```

(The `+ 1` is necessary to match your code.  Python uses half-open intervals, i.e. the first index is included in the slice, but the last isn't.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use either:

```
cmd_list[start:end + 1] = []
```

or

```
del cmd_list[start:end + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be easiest to do it with slicing:

```
cmd_list = cmd_list[:start] + cmd_list[end+1:]
```

we still need end+1 for the second half, but it's still a pretty clear line of code.